# Copying current line from shell in linux

Tags: linux, shell

While setting classpaths in the .bashrc, I was wondering if there was a way to copy the current output from the shell for pasting later into some editor. What I am trying to accomplish is as follows:

1. Get the current file path using pwd, e.g. - /SomeFolder/java/bin
2. Use "some" command to copy the output of pwd into the buffer instead of selecting it using the mouse and copying it.
3. Pasting the path(/SomeFolder/java/bin) in the .bashrc.

I was thinking if there was a way to do it in a mouse free manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pwd | xsel -b

pwd | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: On Mac OSX, pbcopy and pbpaste would accomplish the same trick.

Answer (score 3):

Way too easy:

```
pwd >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually by redirecting output of a command. `pwd >> .bashrc` (note the double >) redirects the output of pwd and adds it to .bashrc instead of to your screen.

You probably want: `echo "export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$(pwd)" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: He probably wants that, but he has to learn to ask his questions the right way ;)

Comment: Great! This would work but is there a way to have the output of the command buffered so that I can yank it to anywhere, .bashrc or just an empty text file?

Comment: Still `pwd >> anywhere_you_want`. Or I didn't understand your question.